# The SharePoint Search Dropdown shows only This site as the scope

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a team site in which the Search scope dropdown only shows This site and it doesn't show All Sites and People in the dropdown.Any one knows why?

I have not enabled Custom scopes in Search settings for this site because I don't have Search Center created. If I create search center and specify as a custom scope in this site I can see all 3 scopes in the dropdown. I am just trying to understand whether I need to have Search Center created to have all these shared scopes getting displayed in the Search Scopes drop down?

Answer (score 1):

Go to site settings-->site collection admistration-->search scopes-->we can see the display group
Edit **SearhDropdown** display group--> There we can choose all site and people scopes

Answer (score 0):

According to http://insidesharepoint.blogspot.com/2007/06/and-now-another-word-form-our.html , the first step in debugging why all of your scopes are not available is to ensure that you have a Search Center site created.

So yes, it appears that Search Center is a requirement in order to see anything other than "This Site:" / "This List:"